# Orchard core GraphiQL does not display my added field

Tags: graphql, orchardcms

I started my project on Orchard Core Cms with .NET 6. When I try to execute graphql query on GraphiQL tool on Orchard Core it does not display the field "description" which I added to the fields of ProductCategory content item
The query is like below:

```
query MyQuery {
  productCategory {
    id
    description
    bag {
      contentItems {
        ... on ProductCategory {
          description
          bag {
            contentItems {
              ... on ProductCategory {
                id
                description
                displayText
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the response is as follow:

```
{
  "data": {
    "productCategory": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "Product Category 1 Description",
        "bag": {
          "contentItems": [
            {
              "bag": {
                "contentItems": [
                  {
                    "id": 15,
                    // description field is absent
                    "displayText": "Product Category 3"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

ProductCategory content type has two fields: `Id` and `Description` and enjoys `Title`, `Flow`, `Bag`, `Alias` parts. Moreover, this content type can be bag of ProductCategory content type. As it visible in the code, the first item displays the `description` field but the child item ignores it

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to enable `Autoroute` feature and now everything works like a charm

Comment: On my case I disabled the graphiql and re enable it.